# Two apps on heroku under one domain with subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was wondering if anyone could give me some help / advice on how it would be possible to run two separate apps on Heroku under the same domain. Except one would be accessed using domain.com and the other one would be accessed using dev.domain.com.

Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing it?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially add it as a staging app in your pipeline just adding your subdomain of `dev.domain.com` as your custom domain.